# How can I make a Grafana template with a variable reference another variable using Elasticsearch as a datasource?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, grafana-templating

I have a Grafana dashboard with template variables for fields and terms . When I select a field how can I make it filter the second template variable list based on the first?

The first part is working when i use {"find": "fields", "type": "string"} >> I am able to see all the fields in my database now I could not figure how to create the second template variable

{"find": "fields", "type": "string"}

I expect to filter the exact result based on the two template variables.